# How can I close a dask_mpi cluster?

Tags: dask, slurm, dask-distributed

I would like to have a dask minimal running example on an mpi cluster, so I could develop from it.

However, I don't know how to properly finalize the thing, and I can't find many examples anywhere.

This is the script I submit to slurm:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dask_mpi as dm
import dask.distributed as dd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dm.initialize(local_directory=os.getcwd())
    with dd.Client() as client:
        x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
        y = x * x
        plt.plot(x, y)
        print('Computation complete! Stopping workers...')

    print('Execution complete!')
```

They run fine, but at the end, I get this:

```
Computation complete! Stopping workers...
Execution complete!
2023-08-04 15:58:32,268 - distributed.scheduler - INFO - Receive client connection: Client-c2d12c68-32df-11ee-bf3c-a0369f214ab8
2023-08-04 15:58:32,268 - distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection to tcp://134.94.1.45:55692
2023-08-04 15:58:32,270 - distributed.worker - INFO - Run out-of-band function 'stop'
2023-08-04 15:58:32,271 - distributed.scheduler - INFO - Scheduler closing...
2023-08-04 15:58:32,271 - distributed.scheduler - INFO - Scheduler closing all comms
2023-08-04 15:58:32,271 - distributed.core - INFO - Connection to tcp://134.94.1.46:59274 has been closed.
2023-08-04 15:58:32,271 - distributed.scheduler - INFO - Remove worker <WorkerState 'tcp://134.94.1.46:40107', name: 2, status: running, memory: 0, processing: 0> (stimulus_id='handle-worker-cleanup-1691164712.27189')
2023-08-04 15:58:32,272 - distributed.worker - INFO - Stopping worker at tcp://134.94.1.46:40107. Reason: scheduler-close
2023-08-04 15:58:32,272 - distributed.scheduler - INFO - Lost all workers
2023-08-04 15:58:32,272 - distributed.core - INFO - Received 'close-stream' from tcp://134.94.1.44:39517; closing.
2023-08-04 15:58:32,272 - distributed.batched - INFO - Batched Comm Closed <TCP (closed) Worker->Scheduler local=tcp://134.94.1.46:59274 remote=tcp://134.94.1.44:39517>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/strube1/dask/sc_venv_template/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/batched.py", line 115, in _background_send
    nbytes = yield coro
  File "/home/strube1/dask/sc_venv_template/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 767, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/strube1/dask/sc_venv_template/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 269, in write
    raise CommClosedError()
distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError
```

I have been trying to use dask_mpi to set up a dask cluster over infiniband on our supercomputers. I can't use the simple localcluster for that.

On the other machine, it never finishes:

```
Computation complete! Stopping workers...
Execution complete!
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Receive client connection: Client-1616fc2e-32e1-11ee-943d-080038c02b5f
distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
distributed.worker - INFO - Run out-of-band function 'stop'
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Scheduler closing...
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Scheduler closing all comms
distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at:   tcp://10.13.27.249:44981
distributed.worker - INFO -          Listening to:   tcp://10.13.27.249:44981
distributed.worker - INFO -          dashboard at:         10.13.27.249:43201
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:   tcp://10.13.23.246:45221
distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at:   tcp://10.13.27.249:40555
distributed.worker - INFO -          Listening to:   tcp://10.13.27.249:40555
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -               Threads:                          1
distributed.worker - INFO -          dashboard at:         10.13.27.249:44089
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:   tcp://10.13.23.246:45221
distributed.worker - INFO -                Memory:                 503.45 GiB
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -       Local Directory: /p/home/jusers/strube1/juwels/dask/dask-worker-space/worker-jw56i_pm
distributed.worker - INFO -               Threads:                          1
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -                Memory:                 503.45 GiB
distributed.worker - INFO -       Local Directory: /p/home/jusers/strube1/juwels/dask/dask-worker-space/worker-60rszoo4
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:   tcp://10.13.23.246:45221
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:   tcp://10.13.23.246:45221
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:   tcp://10.13.23.246:45221
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:   tcp://10.13.23.246:45221
```

Comment: There is an open issue for the first error: https://github.com/dask/dask-mpi/issues/94. However, I'm not sure about your second issue. Worker process should be exited at some point.

Comment: How do you define `cluster` in the first snippet?

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev sorry, cluster here is not needed, as it comes from the dask-mpi. It's `with dd.Client() as client:`